# Pass data between BroadcastReceivers Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-broadcastreceiver

I have to BroadCastReceivers: one is for listening data from Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), another one is for screen state as follows:

```
private String sreenState="";
public class ScreenStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            sreenState="screen on";

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "screen on");
            sreenState="screen on";
        }
    }
}


private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            String data=intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
            Log.d("TAG",sreenState);
        }
    }
}
```

In the BroadcastReceiver of BLE, I want to show the current state of the screen via `screenState` variable, when `ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE` happen. However, it always returns the previous state of the screen. For example, the screen is off, and I received data, it will shows  "null." If the screen is on, and I received data, then the result of the state is off. I think it is synchronous issue. How can i solve it? Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

You can also read the current screen state within the BLE receiver itself as:

```
mIsScreenOn = ((PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isScreenOn();
```

Comment: I want to use above broadcast because I need to check the on, off, lock of screen, instead of only screen on

Comment: @user8430 I personally avoid relying on `BroadcastReceiver`s for synchronous communication because most of the time even system level broadcasts are substantially delayed